# Composing Pipes into a loop or cycle in haskell

Tags: haskell, composition, haskell-pipes

This question is about the Haskell library [Pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes).

This question is related to 2019 [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) [Day 11](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/11) (possible spoiler warning)

I have two `Pipe Int Int m r` `brain` and `robot` that need to pass information too each other in a continuous loop.  That is the output of `brain` need to go to the input of `robot` and the output of `robot` needs to go the the input of `brain`.  When `brain` finished I need the result of the computation.

How do I compose `brain` and `robot` into a loop? Ideally a loop with the type `Effect m r` that I can pass to `runEffect`

Edit: The result should look like this:

```
   +-----------+     +-----------+   
   |           |     |           |   
   |           |     |           |   
a ==>    f    ==> b ==>    g    ==> a=|
^  |           |     |           |    |
|  |     |     |     |     |     |    |
|  +-----|-----+     +-----|-----+    |
|        v                 v          |
|        ()                r          |
+=====================================+
```

Comment: "pass information back and forth". `Pipe`s are unidirectional. If you need bidirectionality, perhaps you could use the `Client` and `Server` types and the  `request`, `respond`, `(+>>)` and `(>>~)` functions from `Pipes.Core`http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html

Comment: Sorry not clear.  the information flows only one direction, but it flows around a closed loop.  I'm trying to figure out how to close the loop.

Comment: I think you'll need to decide what should happen when the number of `await`s don't match with the number of `yield`s. There is no good solution for that. The alternative of `request` and `respond` solves this by forcing them to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The answer

The easiest solution would be to use `Client` and `Server` as danidiaz suggested in the comments, since `pipes` doesn't have any built in support for cyclic pipes and it would be incredibly difficult, if not impossible to do so correctly. This is mostly because we need to handle cases where the number of `await`s doesn't match the number of `yield`s.

**Edit:** I added a section about the problems with the other answer. See section "Another problematic alternative"

**Edit 2:** I have added a less problematic possible solution below. See the section "A possible solution"

### A problematic alternative

It is however possible to simulate it with the help of the [`Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:generalize) framework (with `Client` and `Server`) and the neat function [`generalize`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:generalize), which turns a unidirectional `Pipe` into a bidirectional `Proxy`.

```
                                       generalize f x0
   +-----------+                   +---------------------+
   |           |                   |                     |
   |           |                x <======================== x
a ==>    f    ==> b   becomes      |                     |
   |           |                a ==>         f         ==> b
   |     |     |                   |                     |
   +-----|-----+                   +----------|----------+
         v                                    v     
         r                                    r
```

Now we can use [`//>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html#v:-47--47--62-) and [`>\\`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html#v:-62--92--92-) to plug the ends and make the flow cyclic:

```hs
loop :: Monad m => Pipe a a m r -> a -> Effect m r
loop p x0 = pure >\\ generalize p x0 //> pure
```

which has this shape

```
            loop f

              a 
        +-----|-----+
        |     |     |
 /====<=======/===<========\
 |      |           |      |
 \=> a ==>    f    ==> a ==/
        |           |
        +-----|-----+
              v    
              r
```

As you can see, we are required to input an initial value for `a`. This is because there is no guarantee that the pipe won't `await` before it yields, which would force it to wait forever.

Note however that this **will throw away data** if the pipe `yield`s multiple times before `await`ing, since generalize is internally implemented with a state monad that saves the last value when yielding and retrieves the last value when awaiting.

#### Usage (of the problematic idea)

To use it with your pipes, simply compose them and give them to `loop`:

```hs
runEffect $ loop (f >-> g)
```

But please don't use it, since it will randomly throw away data if you are not careful

### Another problematic alternative

You could also make a lazily infinite chain of pipes like mingmingrr suggested

```
infiniteChain :: Functor m => Pipe a a m r -> Producer a m r
infiniteChain f = infiniteChain >-> f
```

This solves the problem of discarded/duplicated values, but has several other problems. First is that awaiting first before yielding will cause an infinite loop with infinite memory usage, but that is already addressed in mingmingrr's answer.

Another, more difficult to solve, issue is that every action before the corresponding yield is duplicated once for each await. We can see this if we modify their example to log what is happening:

```hs
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

f :: Monad m => Pipe Int Int m r
f = P.map (* 2)

g :: Monad m => Int -> Pipe Int Int m ()
g 0 = return ()
g n = do
  lift . putStrLn $ "Awaiting. n = " ++ show n
  x <- await
  lift . putStrLn $ "Got: x = " ++ show x ++ " and n = "++ show n ;
  yield (x + 1)
  g (n - 1)

cyclic' :: Monad m => Int -> Producer Int m Int
cyclic' input = let pipe = (yield input >> pipe) >-> f >-> g 6 in pipe
```

Now, running `runEffect (cyclic' 0 >-> P.print)` will print the following:

```
Awaiting. n = 6
Got: x = 0 and n = 6
1
Awaiting. n = 5
Awaiting. n = 6
Got: x = 0 and n = 6
Got: x = 2 and n = 5
3
Awaiting. n = 4
Awaiting. n = 5
Awaiting. n = 6
Got: x = 0 and n = 6
Got: x = 2 and n = 5
Got: x = 6 and n = 4
7
Awaiting. n = 3
Awaiting. n = 4
Awaiting. n = 5
Awaiting. n = 6
Got: x = 0 and n = 6
Got: x = 2 and n = 5
Got: x = 6 and n = 4
Got: x = 14 and n = 3
15
Awaiting. n = 2
Awaiting. n = 3
Awaiting. n = 4
Awaiting. n = 5
Awaiting. n = 6
Got: x = 0 and n = 6
Got: x = 2 and n = 5
Got: x = 6 and n = 4
Got: x = 14 and n = 3
Got: x = 30 and n = 2
31
Awaiting. n = 1
Awaiting. n = 2
Awaiting. n = 3
Awaiting. n = 4
Awaiting. n = 5
Awaiting. n = 6
Got: x = 0 and n = 6
Got: x = 2 and n = 5
Got: x = 6 and n = 4
Got: x = 14 and n = 3
Got: x = 30 and n = 2
Got: x = 62 and n = 1
63
```

As you can see, for each `await`, we re-executed everything until the corresponding `yield`. More specifically, an await triggers a new copy of the pipe to run until it reaches a yield. When we await again, the copy will run until the next yield again and if it triggers an `await` during that, it will create yet another copy and run it until the first yield, and so on.

This means that in the best case, we get `O(n^2)` instead of linear performance (And using `O(n)` instead of `O(1)` memory), since we are repeating everything for each action. In the worst case, e.g. if we were reading from or writing to a file, we could get completely wrong results since we are repeating side-effects.

### A possible solution

If you really must use `Pipe`s and can't use `request`/`respond` instead and you are sure that your code will never `await` more than (or before) it `yield`s (or have a good default to give it in those cases), we could build upon my previous attempt above to make a solution that at least handles the case when `yield`ing more than you `await`.

The trick is adding a buffer to the implementation of `generalize`, so the excess values are stored instead of being thrown away. We can also keep the extra argument as a default value for when the buffer is empty.

```hs
import Pipes.Lift (evalStateP)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict (state, modify)
import qualified Data.Sequence

generalize' :: Monad m => Pipe a b m r -> x -> Proxy x a x b m r
generalize' p x0 = evalStateP Seq.empty $ up >\\ hoist lift p //> dn
  where
    up () = do
        x <- lift $ state (takeHeadDef x0)
        request x
    dn a = do
        x <- respond a
        lift $ modify (Seq.|> x)
    takeHeadDef :: a -> Seq.Seq a -> (a, Seq.Seq a)
    takeHeadDef x0 xs = (foldr const x0 xs, Seq.drop 1 xs)
```

If we now plug this into our definition of of `loop`, we will have solved the problem of discarding excess values (at the memory cost of keeping a buffer). It also prevents duplicating any values other than the default value and only uses the default value when the buffer is empty.

```
loop' :: Monad m => a -> Pipe a a m r -> Effect m r
loop' x0 p = pure >\\ generalize' p x0 //> pure
```

If we want `await`ing before `yield`ing to be an error, we can simply give `error` as our default value: `loop' (error "Await without yield") somePipe`.

### TL;DR

Use `Client` and `Server` from [`Pipes.Core`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html). It will solve your problem and not cause a ton of strange bugs.

If that is not possible, my "Possible solution" section with a modified version of `generalize` should do the job in most cases.

Comment: Ok, Your point is well taken, but I am confused by the Pipes.Core documentation on request and respond.  I have opened another question seeking clairification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333006/using-request-and-response-in-with-the-pipes-library-for-bidirectional-communica

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cyclic pipe by tying the output of the pipe into the input.

```
cyclic :: Functor m => Producer a m r
cyclic = cyclic >-> f >-> g
```

Consider the following example:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

f :: Monad m => Pipe Int Int m r
f = P.map (* 2)

g :: Monad m => Int -> Pipe Int Int m Int
g 0 = return 100
g n = do x <- await ; yield (x + 1) ; g (n - 1)
```

Since neither `f` nor `g` here yields any output before awaiting, using `cyclic = cyclic >-> f >-> g` would result in `f` awaiting forever. The key to avoiding this is making sure either `f` or `g` yields something before awaiting, or feeding in the initial input to the first pipe like so:

```
cyclic' :: Monad m => Int -> Producer Int m Int
cyclic' input = let pipe = (yield input >> pipe) >-> f >-> g 6 in pipe
```

Here running `runEffect (cyclic' 0 >-> P.print)` gives `return 100` and prints `1 3 7 15 31 63`.

P.S. (possible Advent of Code 2019 spoilers) You can use this same scheme to complete day 7. If your Intcode computer has type `StateT IntcodeState (Pipe Int Int m)`, then you can use `replicate 5 (evalState runIntcode initialIntcodeState)` to get 5 pipes corresponding to each of the 5 amplifiers.

Comment: Is there any performance penalty for using an infinite chain of pipes like in loop? What happens if `f` and `g` are stateful?
Also, I think `cyclic'` is missing an argument in `yield input >> cyclic' `.

Comment: It's more like a close pipe loop rather than an infinite chain of pipes, so the performance should be similar to something like `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. `f` and `g` can still be stateful since there's no constrain on `m` other than `Monad m`.

Comment: Here's an example: Say `f = cat`, `g = do {lift $ putStrLn "hello"; yield "a"; await}`. This will print "hello" twice, despite only yielding a single value. Is this intended?

Comment: Ah, seems like anything before the first yield gets executed twice, so reordering `g` to `g = do { yield "a" ; lift (putStrLn "hello") ; await }` makes it only print "hello" once.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem is that you are not actually making a loop, just a potentially infinite chain of pipes that can be called whenever a part of the chain needs more values. Everything before a second yield will also be executed twice. And in that case, everything before the first yield is executed three times.

Comment: I am confident that your solution is `O(n^2)`, since every await will cause everything before the corresponding yield to be re-executed. This is the performance-problem I was talking about.

Comment: See my answer for a longer demonstration of this problem.