# Using request and response in with the Pipes library for bidirectional communication

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

This question is about the Haskell [Pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) library

**Background:**

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280156/composing-pipes-into-a-loop-or-cycle-in-haskell), I asked how to form a cycle using pipes and [the answer I got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280156/composing-pipes-into-a-loop-or-cycle-in-haskell/59289637#59289637) was "don't do that.  Use `request` and `response` instead."  While there is an excellent and clearly written [tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) that covers `Producers`, `Consumers`, `Pipes`, and `Effects` in plain English.  The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Core.html) for `request` and `response` `Client` and `Server` starts by defining [Categories](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html#g:2) and mentioning some other CompSci concepts like "[the generator design pattern.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html#g:3)" and "[the iteratee design pattern](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/Pipes-Core.html#g:4)." which are never explained. So I'm stuck not knowing how to "use `request` and `response` instead."

**The Setup**

I have two state-machines like thing that need to pass data back and forth repeatedly, `robot` and `intCode`.

The Robot is pretty simple:

```
robot :: Pipe Int Int m r -- robot never returns so its return type is polymorphic
robot = go newRobot
  where
    go r = do
      yield $ color r
      c <- toColor <$> await 
      turn <- toTurn <$> await
      go $ update c turn r
```

It `yield`s a value, `await`s *two* instructions (a new color and a turn), updates the state (`r`) of the robot, and starts over.

The `intCode` virtual machine runs programmed to communicate with the robot. It takes a program (called `code`) and creates a pipe that will `await` the sensor reading from the robot then `yield` two instructions to it.

```
(boot code) :: Pipe Int Int m ()
```

Let's assume that the IntCode VM is not easily modified, but that the robot is.

**Questions:**

How are `request` and `respond` different from `await` and `yield`?

How do I use them to facilitate continuous communication between the robot and the VM?

Comment: interestingly, the [package blurb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13) says "Advantages over traditional streaming libraries: <...>  Bidirectionality: Implement duplex channels" but it doesn't say "... Implements duplex channels"; and "duplex" is not in the [index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.13/docs/doc-index-D.html) (that's all I know).

Answer (score 3):

The definitions of `await` and `yield` are:

```
await = request ()
yield = respond
```

so they are closely related to `request` and `respond`.  The `await` and `yield` versions have just been specialized to unidirectional pull-based streams (`Producer`s, `Pipe`s and `Consumer`s).

To perform bidirectional communication between two endpoints, you want to set up a `Client` and a `Server` and connect them.

A `Client` is a monadic action that makes requests:

```
y <- request x
```

by sending request `x` and receiving response `y`.  A `Server` is a monadic action that responds:

```
x <- respond y
```

by accepting request `x` and sending response `y`.  Note that these operations are symmetric, so in a given application it's arbitrary which half is the `Client` and which half is the `Server`.

Now, you may notice that while the `Client` sends an `x` and receives a `y` in response, the `Server` seems backward.  It sends response `y` before receiving request `x`!  In fact, it just needs to operate one step behind -- a server in a pull-based stream will want to send its response `y` to the **previous** request in order to receive the **next** request `x`.

As a simple example, here's a `Client` that requests addition of numbers to calculate powers of two:

```
-- |Client to generate powers of two
power2 :: Client (Int, Int) Int IO ()
power2 = go 1
  where go n | n <= 1024 = do
          liftIO $ print n
          n' <- request (n,n)   -- ask adder to add "n" and "n"
          go n'
        go n = liftIO $ print "Done"
```

Writing the server to add numbers is a little trickier because of this "one step behind" business.  We might start by writing:

```
-- |Server to sum numbers
sum2 :: Server (Int, Int) Int IO ()
sum2 = do
  (n,n) <- respond ???   -- send previous response to get current request
  let n' = n+n
  ??? <- respond n'      -- send current reponse to get next request
```

The trick is to get things started by accepting the first request as an argument to the monadic action:

```
-- |Server to sum numbers
sum2 :: (Int, Int) -> Server (Int, Int) Int IO ()
sum2 (m, n) = do
  (m', n') <- respond (m+n)  -- send response to get next request
  sum2 (m', n')              -- and loop
```

Fortunately, the pull point-ful connector `+>>` has the right type to connect these:

```
mypipe :: Effect IO ()
mypipe = sum2 +>> power2
```

and we can run the resulting effect in the usual manner:

```
main :: IO ()
main = runEffect mypipe

ghci> main
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
"Done"
```

Note that, for this type of bidirectional communication, requests and responses need to run in synchronous lock-step, so you can't do the equivalent of yielding once and awaiting twice.  If you wanted to re-design the example above to send requests in two parts, you'd need to develop a protocol with sensible request and response types, like:

```
data Req = First Int | Second Int
data Res = AckFirst | Answer Int

power2 = ...
    AckFirst <- request n
    Answer n' <- request n
sum2 = ...
    First m' <- respond (Answer (m+n))
    Second n' <- respond AckFirst
    ...
```

For your brain/robot application, you can design the robot as either a client:

```
robotC :: Client Color (Color,Turn) Identity ()
robotC = go newRobot
  where
    go r = do
      (c, turn) <- request (color r)
      go $ update c turn r
```

or a server:

```
robotS :: Server (Color,Turn) Color Identity ()
robotS = go newRobot
  where
    go r = do
      (c, turn) <- respond (color r)
      go $ update c turn r
```

Because the robot produces output before consuming input, as a client it will fit into a pull-based stream with a brain server:

```
brainS :: Color -> Server Color (Color,Turn) Identity ()
brainS = ...

approach1 = brainS +>> robotC
```

or as a server it will fit into a push-based stream with a brain client:

```
brainC :: Color -> Client (Color,Turn) Color Identity ()
brainC = ...

approach2 = robotS >>~ brainC
```